# The variable is being used and not being initialized

Tags: c++

This is a program for a basic C++ Programming class. Variable foodPrice and bisPrice are giving me the error of being used without being initialized and they can't be passed by reference. I'm not sure how to initialize them. Please help. Thanks

```
using namespace std;

void getBiscuits( string &, double & );
void getDryFood( string & , double & );
void processData( double, double , double & , double & , double & , double , double );
void displayOrder( string , string , string , double , double , double , double , double , double , double , double , double , double );

const double foodCost = 30;
const double bisCost = 10;
const double salesTax = .07;

int main()
{
    //declare variables
    string name;
    double numBis;
    string bis;
    string dryFood;
    double foodNum;
    double bisPrice;
    double foodPrice;
    double tax = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double subTotal = 0;

    //get data from user
    cout << "Welcome to The Big Dog's Food Panty" << endl;
    cout << "Please tell us your first and last name?" << endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Thanks " << name << endl;
    system ("cls");
    getBiscuits( bis , numBis ) ;
    getDryFood( dryFood , foodNum ) ;
    processData( numBis , foodNum , subTotal , tax , total , bisPrice , foodPrice ) ;
    displayOrder( name ,  bis , dryFood , bisPrice , numBis , bisCost , foodPrice , foodNum , foodCost , subTotal , tax , salesTax , total ) ;

    // stop to let the user read the far
    system ("pause");
}

void getBiscuits( string &bis , double &numBis )
{
    string dummyVariable;

    cout << "Would you like the Spicy Chicken or BBQ Beef biscuits?" << endl;
    getline(cin, bis);
    system ("cls");
    cout << "How many five lb bags of " << bis << " would you like?" << endl;
    cin >> numBis;
    getline(cin, dummyVariable);
    system ("cls");
}

void getDryFood( string &dryFood , double &foodNum )
{
    cout << "Would you like Salmon and Peas or Chicken and Rice dry food?" << endl;
    getline(cin, dryFood);
    system ("cls");
    cout << "How many 28 lbs bags of " << dryFood << " would you like?" << endl;
    cin >> foodNum;
    system ("cls");
}

void processData( double numBis , double foodNum , double &subTotal ,double &tax , double &total , double bisPrice , double foodPrice )
{
    //calculate
    bisPrice = numBis * bisCost;
    foodPrice = foodNum * foodCost;
    subTotal = bisPrice + foodPrice;
    tax = subTotal * salesTax;
    total = subTotal + tax;
}

void displayOrder( string name ,  string bis , string dryFood , double bisPrice , double numBis , double bisCost , double foodPrice , double foodNum , double foodCost , double subTotal ,double tax , double salesTax , double total )
{
    // display cost
    cout << "Thanks " << name << " for your order!" << endl;
    cout << numBis << setprecision(2) << fixed << " five lbs bags of " << bis << " at $10.00 each is $" << bisPrice << endl;
    cout << setprecision(0) << fixed <<foodNum << setprecision(2) << fixed << " 28 lbs bags of " << dryFood << " at $30.00 each is $" << foodPrice << endl;
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << "Your subtotal is $" << subTotal << endl;
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << "Your sales tax is $" << tax << endl;
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << "Your total is $" << total << endl;
}
```

Comment: There isn't even a *single* line of error checking in this entire program.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this and the errors will go:

```
double bisPrice = 0;
double foodPrice = 0;
```

I think it should have been obvious to you that you did not provide any value on declaration :)

And yes do not forget these as well:

```
string name = "";
double numBis = 0;
string bis = "";
string dryFood = "";
double foodNum = 0;
```

Variables in functions have automatic storage hence they are not initialized to a value by default.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define their initial values.

```
double bisPrice; 
double foodPrice;
```

Change to:

```
double bisPrice = 0;
double foodPrice = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your compiler warnings, initialize the variables:

```
double bisPrice = 0; 
double foodPrice = 0;
```

In C and C++ fundamental value types do not have an [initial value](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/).

> When declaring a regular local variable, its value is by default undetermined. But you may want a variable to store a concrete value at the same moment that it is declared. In order to do that, you can initialize the variable.

Objects will be initialized using their default constructor, which is why you don't have the same error for the `string` variables.